# Incrementally add to existing variables in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, constants

Is it possible to create a constant or value like so

```
    app.value('test', {
        a : 'Value 1'
    });

    app.value('test', {
        b : 'Value 2'
    });
```

And both of them actually combine, right now the first one is overwritten. I need something like we used to have in PHP

```
$global_vars = array();
```

And then push all the global vars from different modules as they are available into one global_vars array.

```
$global_vars['Number_of_pages'] = 50;
```

and then somewhere later

```
$global_vars['currency'] = "USD";
```

etc

Comment: You want to use `test` service in different modules config blocks?

Comment: @dfsq basically I want to define some global variables but all should be combined under one name e.g GLOBAL_CONSTANTS , and I will assign these GLOBAL_CONSTANTS from different parts of application, but at the end I want to be able to use them with one name GLOBAL_CONSTANTS.VAR_NAME in modules , and views as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could `extend` an object each time you add properties:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend

Answer (score 1):

Use `constant`, don't use `value`.

> Constant can be available inside config phase of angular, value doesn't

Create one factory with blank constant

```
app.constant('test', {
   //will be blank
});

//set a in app1
app1.config(['test', function (test){
   angular.extend(test,  {a : 'Value 1'})
}]);

//set b in app2
app2.config(['test', function (test){
   angular.extend(test,  {b : 'Value 2'})
}]);
```

You can set like above in different modules.

This could be helpful to you. Thanks.

Comment: This is correct. Just on note that it's important that `constant` should be used, not `value` in order to inject in in config blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Use $rootScope for this. 
Add to $rootScope. Add rootscope by injecting it:

```
.controller('test',['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
//add to root scope
```